# Программа должна удалять те предложения, средняя длина слов которых больше шести

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Проблема в том, что я начал работать со `strings` как с одномерным массивом, а он то двумерный. Что мне переделать с того, что уже есть в цикле while? И еще, функция `Filling()` плохо работает. Чем больше предложений я захочу ввести, тем больше нужно там getchar(). Как это исправить?
Сам код:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>

using namespace std;

void Filling(char **strings, int i)
{
    cout << "Enter your string:" << endl;
    getchar();
    scanf("%s", strings[i]);
}

int main()
{
    system("color f0");
    system("chcp 1251");
    system("cls");

    int count = 0, nos = 0, nol = 0, now = 0, size = 0;
    double avarage = 0;

    cout << "Enter the number of sentences:" << endl;
    cin >> count;

    char **strings = (char**)malloc(count * sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter max size of %d string, but no bigger than 256 symbols\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &size);

        strings[i] = (char*)malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char));
        Filling(strings, i);
    }

    char *ptr = *strings;

    while (nos < count) // пока не пройдем все предложения
    {
        while (*ptr != '.') // пока это предложение
        {
            while (*ptr != ' ' && *ptr != '\0' && *ptr != '\n') // пока это слово
            {
                ptr++; // двигаем указатель
                nol++; // счетчик букв
            }
            ptr++; // двигаем указатель
            now++; // счетчик слов
        }
        nos++; // счетчик предложений
    }

    printf("\n\n\nletters - %d, words - %d, sentences - %d\n\n\n", nol, now, nos);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так, но я использовал Visual studio, а вы похоже Borland, то возможно что то править придется:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("color f0");
    system("chcp 1251");
    system("cls");

    std::vector<std::string> arr;
    std::string str;
    int countStr = 0, countWords = 0, countLet = 0;
    int resultStr = 0, resultWords = 0, resultLet = 0;
    std::vector<int> sizeWords;

    cout << "Enter the number of sentences:" << endl;
    cin >> countStr;
    cin.ignore(1024, '\n');

    for (int i = 0; i < countStr; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Enter string, but no bigger than 256 symbols" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your string:" << endl;
        getline(std::cin, str, '\n');

        // Считаем к-во букв и записываем их в массив
        for (int i = 0; i !=str.length(); i++)
        {
            if (isalpha(str[i]))
            {
                countLet++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (countLet != 0)
                {
                    sizeWords.push_back(countLet);
                }
                countLet = 0;
            }
        }
        // Записываем последнее слово
        if (countLet > 0)
        {
            sizeWords.push_back(countLet);
            countLet = 0;
        }

        int avgLet = 0;
        // Считаем сумму букв
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeWords.size(); i++)
        {
            avgLet += sizeWords[i];
        }

        // Если средняя длина предложения больше 6 символос сохраняем данные
        if (avgLet / sizeWords.size() > 6)
        {
            arr.push_back(str);
            resultLet += avgLet;
            resultWords += sizeWords.size();
            resultStr++;
        }
        sizeWords.clear();
    }

    cout << "Count letters: " << resultLet << " count words: " << resultWords << " count sentences: " << resultStr << endl;


    system("PAUSE");

    return 1;
}
```